# Is there an easy fix for brake lights on my ‘06 Trailblazer?

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, tail-lights, trailblazer

The brake lights on my ‘06 6-cylinder 2wd Chevy Trailblazer are both out. I tried changing bulbs, and then checked fuses. Neither solved the problem.

Has anyone run into this or can anyone help me troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2):

The only items left to check are:

1) the switch : feed, then does it work when the pedal is moved

2) if switch works, then check the wire between front and rear - has it been cut or damaged and corroded...

Comment: Another clue can be the cruise control:  if the brake switch is jenky, the cruise usually will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the diagram for your stop lamps, hopefully it will help you trace the problem down, its either a fuse, brake switch or a connector near the rear lamps that has become disconnected or cut.

[image]